# How Do I Enable Bookmarks in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, bookmarks

I am using Eclipse (Version: Helios Service Release 2 Build id: 20110301-1815) for a PHP project and would like to use the Bookmark feature. However, right-clicking in the margin shows the Add Bookmark item dimmed out. The Edit menu also shows it dimmed out. For that matter, Add Task is also dimmed out in both locations.

How do I turn on this feature?

Comment: I had a heck of a time with Helios and PHP.  All sorts of things were flaky.  I updated to Indigo a week back and everything resolved itself. So if no other answer can resolve your issue, updating may do the trick for you too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're in a project and that the file you want to place a bookmark in belongs to that project. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Ah! That must be it. I had problems setting up the project with the files on a remote server, so I'm just using the IDE right now to open individual files. I was hoping for a "bookmark" feature similar to Notepad++. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Thats kind of sad, there could (should?) also be the possibility to add bookmarks for any file you can look at (also depending jars). Because right now I just added a debug-breakpoint to a depending-jar's file so that I can easily remember the place to look at in that file. So if I can add a breakpoint which will be remembered, why isn't the bookmark feature working in the same way?